# “jmx_prometheus_javaagent” not working on Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

I am trying to add prometheus jmx agent (jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar) to an existing kafka cluster.

But when I run the java agent, I am not getting response on the port as it says-

```
curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8080; Connection refused
```

Here is my configuration file "kafka.service":

```
[kafka@Kafka-dev prometheus]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
[Unit]
Description=Kafka
After=network.target

[Service]
User=kafka
Group=kafka
Environment="KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx256M -Xms128M"
Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/home/kafka/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=8080:/home/kafka/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml"
ExecStart=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /home/kafka/kafka/config/server.properties
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then when I start Kafka.service it looks that it works:

```
sudo systemctl restart kafka
```

But when I check the status I find that the service is inactive:

```
[kafka@Kafka-dev ~]$ sudo systemctl status kafka.service
    ● kafka.service - Kafka
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-12-05 10:00:17 UTC; 1min 0s ago
      Process: 125469 ExecStart=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /home/kafka/kafka/config/server.properties (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 125469 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Note- firewalls on the machine are disabled.
 I'm suspecting this has something to do with the configuration of jmx_prometheus_javaagent.

Comment: Have you run `systemctl daemon reload` to reload service file?